# Swagger UI accessible without triggering AzureAD authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure-active-directory, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have asp.net mvc project with .NET Framework 4.7.2. Now I added the Swagger nuget package (Install-Package Swashbuckle -Version 5.6.0) to this existing project. Post that I see a SwaggerConfig.cs added to the App_Start folder of the Solution Explorer.

Here the asp.net mvc controllers are used by application pointing to the server: [www.app1.com](http://www.app1.com). This application is also AzureAD authenticated. Hence any request related to application has to go through AzureAD and then complete authentication and authorization (application level) and then navigate to the starting page of the application. Now in case when I tried to navigate to [www.app1.com/swagger](http://www.app1.com/swagger) in another browser , I see it is loading the SwaggerUI for me without prompting for AzureAD authentication.

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This link : http://www.whoiskevinrich.com/restricting-access-to-routes-without-authorize-filter helped to solve the issue :)